# Financial data Python API

Tags: python, api, finance

I'm developing a financial app, and I'm in need for a financial data API which can provide me historical end of day prices for the stocks, both American and European stocks, news, dividends history, sector and industry information.

I'm having a hard time finding such an API or a data provider. Due to I'm just starting out I wish to find a data provider who is either free or reasonable priced, not interested in paying thousands of dollars for the data.

Does anyone here have any experience with such an API and any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

Its worth to check out:

- https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/
- https://finnhub.io/

Both available free

Comment: it's worth checking out also https://tepiloradata.com , fully comprehensive of European ETFs and Funds, not free but very good value. @Willem-Hendriks @ Waleed-Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

I like these packages:

- https://github.com/alvarobartt/investpy – for anything on stock exchanges.
- https://github.com/man-c/pycoingecko – for anything crypto.

Consider using https://github.com/ymyke/tessa, it unifies and simplifies access to investpy and pycoingecko. It also takes care of caching and rate limiting. (Disclosure: I'm the author or tessa.)